# Processing and understanding sentences

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, nlp, analysis, data-analysis

I am trying to write a simple code that can process words in a sentence to form meaning. I have been trying to develop a good algorithm for a long while now, and however I try to do it the algorithm is scaringly tending to be too complex and long. Please if you have some suggestions, I'd appreciate. Thanks

Comment: simple... process words... I see a potential problem here...

Comment: This is an incredibly complex problem with many many people researching it. I'm not going to say there doesn't exist a simple method, but I will say that if it does exist no one has found it yet.

Comment: That's funny. I am expecting hear discouraging sentences filled with AI jargon.

Comment: You can ask IBM how they did Watson http://www-943.ibm.com/innovation/us/watson/ but I doubt they will give you a simple answer.

Comment: @NullSet: Indeed you are right, I'm still experimenting with a lot of ideas, just posted my current solution though, so far this seems to work for most cases since the underlying theory interprets a lot. My current major problem now is generating sentences in reply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm to understand meaning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485748/algorithm-to-understand-meaning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turned out the algorithm has to be complex and long since the brain is actually complex and deep. I have made advances with my code but it's nothing easy. My approach was to use an information database which is analyzed by inspecting every words in each sentence and their meanings + associations but no matter how hard I try, I figured out understanding can only be simulated. For instance:

### My pocket is full of bugs.

*Will be understood as:*

> Animal Bugs are in your pocket.

**Implications:**

- You are in trouble
- You are a bug collector
- You want to use bugs for something

> Electronic Bugs are in your pocket

**Implications**

- Bugs are planted in your pocket
- You have some electronic bugs

The word database for bug (*NOUN*) being:

*Bug (Animal)*

- Definition: Insect.
- Properties: Width: 15mm; Height: 25mm; Color: Black, Red, Orange;
  Importance: Relative - Biology; Danger: 2; Desirability: 0;
- Function: Base

*Bug (Device)*

- Definition: Electronic device.
- Properties: Width: 45mm; Height: 45mm; Color: Any; Importance: Relative - Security; Danger: 2; Desirability: 1
- Function: Sound Recording

The two simulated meanings at least can be deduced from the above and the algorithm makes an intelligent guess to begin a series of questions in order to find out exactly what is meant.

Comment: The best example of how hard English is that I know of is the following sentence: "Time flies like an arrow; fruit flies like a banana". Notice how the *grammatical categories* of the words "flies" and "like" change depending on the meanings of words around it.  IOW it's not always possible to infer the grammar of a sentence without already "knowing what it means".

Comment: Ha ha, English is indeed complex and a great problem to artificial intelligence. There is even [ROILA](http://www.roila.org) - a language specifically made for robots. My resolve is that as far as idioms are concerned, the explanations are relative and should be recorded by the understanding processor based on different people.

Answer (score 2):

You are discussing the field of Natural Language Processing (NLP). It is a very complex issue, and an area of active research.

It is safe to say there will never be a simple way of parsing a general English sentence, let alone establishing meaning.

The School of Informatics at the Univeristy of Sussex has a set of [NLP lectures](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/research/groups/nlp/gazdar/teach/nlp/nlp.html) online that may help you to understand some of the issues which make this such a hard problem.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it's tough. I have also looked at the problems it's facing. I am currently reading Speech Language Processing, and I feel strongly this can be done without so much fuss like many are taking over it.

Comment: @opatachibueze: I realize you may feel strongly that it can be done, but I think everyone would be much more interested in hearing why you THINK it can be done. Then we would all have something to discuss.

Comment: Yep, nice question. I think it can be done because my method of developing algorithms is based on the practical steps I take to do it without automation. Likewise, I believe I can develop a 'software memory', from which I can correlate data to find purpose and meaning simultaneously. The major task in my belief is finding out how best to correlate data without getting mad. Purpose can be found by understanding context using a tags/synonyms trend, and meaning can be created by defining purpose..

Comment: @opatachibueze, I believe that technique will founder if it underestimates the innate steps taken by our brain, which is highly developed for certain tasks without conscious thought. e.g. I do not have any idea *how* I can  focus one speaker out of a crowd; but I can still do it.

Comment: You can focus on one speaker out of a crowd based on sound, motion, appearance. These parameters are also connected to a "Similarity" parameter. The focusing itself is done by your brain. You hear all the sound around you, but you filter out the one coming from the user, which is identifed in the first instance by your synchronizing the sound direction, movement of lips and demonstration (if applicable) by the user. Our brain uses raw power intelligence hard to understand in nature, but we can reproduce it on a PC and I'm just trying to reproduce the part that deals with this:)