# Algorithm to understand meaning

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, nlp, semantics

I want to know if is there any specific algorithm that can be followed to understand the meaning of a word/sentence/paragraph. Basically, I want to write a program that will take text/paragraph as input and try to find out what its meaning is. And thereby highlight the emotions within the text.

Also, if there is an algorithm to understand things, can the same algorithm be applied to itself? It reduces the quest further to a point where we become interested in knowing meaning of meaning OR rather definition of definition.

Comment: Anything else you want to know?

Comment: Input to algorithm: text. Output of algorithm: ??? Emotions ??? :D

Comment: *imagine* there is an algorithm to do this.. how should the output look like? :) ":DDDDDDD"

Comment: @Gens: yeah it made my day :)

Comment: It's called Artificial Intelligence. What you're looking for are *Artificial Neural Networks*.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq More precisely, it's called [semantic parsing](https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&q=%22semantic+parsing%22) or [natural language understanding](https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&q=%22natural+language+understanding%22).

Answer (score 11):

You want [Natural Language Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) and [Semantic Technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_technology). This is still a flourishing area in computer science. Look at things such as a [Semantic Reasoner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_reasoner). You can start with [Jena](http://jena.sourceforge.net/). There are also other things you can look at such as Academic Thesis papers.

Comment: thanks man,, i have tried exploring web, but i am not able to find any specific underlying algorithm for this purpose,, any pointers will help.TIA

Comment: @Timothy There may not be any well known algorithms that do this for you at the moment. We were developing IP for something similar at a company I used to work at. I suggest building a list of Axioms, mostly ones that could depict emotions and what they mean. Then you run your ontology through an inference reasoner that might be able to create new facts in your system about the types of emotions. That's all I can give you, I hope it's enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: In general, it is difficult to obtain the precise meaning of an ambiguous English phrase or sentence. [Attempto Controlled English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attempto_Controlled_English) is a machine-readable subset of the English language that avoid this ambiguity.

Comment: @Timothy did you find any algorithm? If you found, can you share with us? This theme is interesting to me too.